# Neo4j paginated query optimization

Tags: database, optimization, neo4j, cypher, query-optimization

I have two queries, one is the usual way one might write a paginated query

```
MATCH (e:Event), (e)--(l:Place), (e)--(u:User)
OPTIONAL MATCH (e)--(ls:LiveStream)
WITH e {
  .*,
  _id: id(e),
  location: properties(l),
  livestream: properties(ls),
  photos: [(e)--(p:Photo) | p.url],
  createdAt: toString(e.createdAt),
  tags: [(e)--(t:Tag) | properties(t)]
} AS event
RETURN event
SKIP $page * $size
LIMIT $size
```

And the next one uses an early `SKIP` AND `LIMIT` on the `Event` node

```
MATCH (e:Event)
WITH e SKIP $page * $size LIMIT $size
MATCH (e)--(l:Place), (e)--(u:User)
OPTIONAL MATCH (e)--(ls:LiveStream)
WITH e {
  .*,
  _id: id(e),
  location: properties(l),
  livestream: properties(ls),
  photos: [(e)--(p:Photo) | p.url],
  createdAt: toString(e.createdAt),
  tags: [(e)--(t:Tag) | properties(t)]
} AS event
RETURN event
```

---

Using a `SKIP` value of 0 and `LIMIT` of 10 for both, the query planner for the first one yields

> [image]

while the query planner for the second yields

> [image]

The first seems to traverse the entire db, while the second only starts with 10 `Event` nodes.

What are the pros and cons of either, most especially as the amount of data in the database increases.

Answer (score 0):

The second query:

```
MATCH (e:Event)
WITH e SKIP $page * $size LIMIT $size
MATCH (e)--(l:Place), (e)--(u:User)
OPTIONAL MATCH (e)--(ls:LiveStream)
WITH e {
  .*,
  _id: id(e),
  location: properties(l),
  livestream: properties(ls),
  photos: [(e)--(p:Photo) | p.url],
  createdAt: toString(e.createdAt),
  tags: [(e)--(t:Tag) | properties(t)]
} AS event
RETURN event
```

is the preferred way, because it is only traversing the relationships of 10 event nodes, be it linked to Place, User, Photo, or Tag. Hence, the graph traversed by this query is very small. The only caveat here is that you are using `MATCH` to find links with `Place`, and `User`. So, if any of the 10 event nodes are not linked to any `Place` or `User`. It will get filtered out.

The first query traverses the relationships for all event nodes and then paginates, which renders lots of graph traversals and data-transforming operations useless. It's not much performant because of it.

With increasing graph size, the second query is the way to go. Also, I noticed you are not using the `User` nodes anywhere, so you might wanna remove it, if they are redundant.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. My intuition thought that would be better, but I needed confirmation (it's those clever tricks that get you in the end). It's guaranteed that there will always be a `Place` and `User` linked to any event. I removed some aspects of the return result for brevity.